# Does EF core's HasIndex(Expression<Func<T,object>>) always get the index ordering correct?

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.1

As far as I'm aware, there isn't a reliable, documented way to get anonymous type properties in the order that they're declared in a source file which causes me to wonder if I use EF core's HasIndex thus:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<T>(entity => entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Z, e.A }) )
```

..is it certain that the index will be created in column order Z,A ?

---

I'm less concerned about the `params string` overload form:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<T>(entity => entity.HasIndex("Z", "A") )
```

..because I imagine it would be logical for the array element order to dictate the index column order.

I'm struggling to use this form, however, without hardcoded strings because the `DbSet<X>` is defined thus:

```
public virtual DbSet<X> X {get;set;}
```

..rather than the plural `Xs` (not my rule, but I'm stuck with it), so trying to use `HasIndex(nameof(X.Z), nameof(X.A))` is an error because the nearest accessible X is a collection of X, rather than type X, and hence doesn't have the properties I want to `nameof`

The closest I've been able to come to work around this issue is to instantiate an X:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SessionChargingProfileLog>(entity =>
{
    var x = new X(0, 0, "");

    entity.HasIndex(nameof(x.Z), nameof(x.A)).IsClustered().IncludeProperties(nameof(x.B));

});
```

..which is a bit..

So if it could be concretely confirmed that "yes, the `HasIndex(e => new { e.Z, e.A })` will definitely create the index as Z, A" it'd be be marvellous; I'd test it, but I don't think "try it and observe if it's right in this case" means that it guarantees it will always work out, versus a "yes, it'll work because.."

Comment: Given that EF generates SQL queries based on expression trees (and not on the .NET objects that they would create), I would expect that it also generates INDEX definition statements in the same way, so based on expression trees and not on the .NET objects that they would create. But that is my assumption, not based on hard facts.

Comment: Not that you need it, given Saeed's answer, but the workaround for `nameof` not working in that context is to fully qualify the identifier, from namespace to property. No matter how extensively qualified the name is, the last part is the target identifier of the `nameof` expression (to the dismay of several people who have asked questions about getting qualified names). Full qualification may not be pretty, but it doesn't require an instance of the entity.

Comment: The expression can be deconstructed in the order you'd expect. The compiler uses the RuntimeMethodHandle of the appropriate property and passes them **in order** See this example and note the compiler declares 2 anonymous types, with the constructor parameters in swapped order (look at the parameter names) https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTADAsAUOCMsQQAQngOgDIEsB2AjgNxKrrb4EYCiAHgA4BOApgM6s4D2erJMssABoAKAC4oAvAD4UeZgHcUAbxSiMAQQA0qjACEUAXwCUfATBHjpshcp27ta9YZNn0ANjQAWFIIA8AJSlhOiY2Dm5fEABWXwAVbUCZZgYjJQMUMxYAY05GABMUWOF0VC0UfHFdIxQiIA= The `NewExpression` can therefore be inspected in order as well

Comment: Now I admit that doesn't mean EF actually respects the order, but given that they easily *can* I'm hard pressed trying to imagine them providing such a method if ordering wasn't guaranteed. If that was the case, I'd instead expect them to  expose *only* the string based overload

Comment: I just dug through EF source. They aren't using the NewExpression, instead they look at the MemberAccessExpressions (properties) in the order they are referenced. Same thing basically. What's also important to note is that Expressions are a way to declare the shape of code, not the result. The order has to be maintained, both for introspection but also in the event they are compiled/executed (suppose one property had a side effect, the order needs to be preserved). It's too much code to dig through and try to write an answer from my phone. But the answers below are correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As far as I'm aware, there isn't a reliable, documented way to get anonymous type properties in the order that they're declared in a source file

You are missing the fact that here you are not dealing with anonymous type at runtime via reflection, but with compile time generated expression tree representing anonymous type instantiation. The body of the lambda is [NewExpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.newexpression?view=net-5.0) (not `MemberInit` as it looks syntactically), which is a constructor call with [Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.newexpression.arguments?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Expressions_NewExpression_Arguments) containing the defining expressions in the order you specify them and also mapped to [Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.newexpression.members?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Expressions_NewExpression_Members) which is specifically made for anonymous types:

> The `Members` property provides a mapping between the constructor arguments and the type members that correspond to those values. In the case of the construction of an anonymous type, this property maps the constructor arguments to the properties that are exposed by the anonymous type. This mapping information is important because the fields that are initialized by the construction of an anonymous type, or the properties that access those fields, are not discoverable through the `Constructor` or `Arguments` properties of a `NewExpression` node.

What about the order, the documentation for [Anonymous Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) says:

> If two or more anonymous object initializers in an assembly specify a sequence of properties that are in the same order and that have the same names and types, the compiler treats the objects as instances of the same type. They share the same compiler-generated type information.

So since the order of the initialization is part of the anonymous type identity, then it should be preserved by the complier, and in turn reflected in the compiler generated lambda expression.

Comment: I just dug through EF source. To my surprise, they don't use the NewExpression at all (for this)! Instead they use the MemberAccessExpressions and process them in order

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/eda1513a893f0424c79204090c069eae378f63da/src/EFCore/Metadata/Builders/EntityTypeBuilder%60.cs#L292 and https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/847bf3dedcd81583934bc2f6b8e0fa7ce9356c51/src/EFCore/Infrastructure/ExpressionExtensions.cs#L265 for reference if anyone cares

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Actually they do check `NewExpression`, otherwise it won't work at all. See here https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/eda1513a893f0424c79204090c069eae378f63da/src/EFCore/Extensions/Internal/ExpressionExtensions.cs#L83

Comment: that's what I get for not digging further/paying too much attention. I suspected they had to (see comments on OP), being lazy I guess lol

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `EF` creates index in the same order as you defined, exactly.

Because the order of columns in index is so important in relational databases and all search scenarios are in order of columns for seek indexes (when build the execution plan).

As you know when change the order of columns for specific index you should rebuild that index for create based on new order.